# BigQuery how to order a nested and repeated column?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table containing events that occurred with a certain animal, example purchase, death, birth, etc. Many events occur on different dates but there are events that occur on the same date (format yyyy-mm-dd). For those that occur on the same date, there is the "event_id" column to make the classification. My question is this: how to create a query that returns a nested and repeated column with all events ordered by date + ID, for each existing animal?

```
select animal,
array_agg(struct(event_id, event_date, event_name, event_etc, ...)) as event
from events
group by animal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ARRAY_AGG` supports `ORDER BY` ([ref](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg)). So, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  animal,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(
      event_id,
      event_date,
      event_name,
      ...
    ) ORDER BY event_date, event_id
  ) AS events
FROM events
GROUP BY animal;
```